# Understanding df output inside GKE container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, linux-disk-free

I’m trying out ephemeral storage for the first time.  I have a node with a single 375G local SSD disk (GKE), and a 100G standard boot disk.  For the ephemeral storage, I use `emptyDir`, mount the volume at `/workdir`, and set my request/limit at 20G.   When I exec into the pod and run `df -kh` I see:

```sh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         369G  7.8G  342G   3% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1    369G  7.8G  342G   3% /workdir
shm              64M   24K   64M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           103G     0  103G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I expected `/workdir` to have a size of 20G.  Why do both `/` and `/workdir` seem to be identical, and why do I see nearly the full disk?

Comment: Which Kube version are you using?

Comment: You should also use `du -sh` inside the container rather than `df` if you want to see the usage.

Comment: The cluster is running 1.18.12-gke.1210.  I am not interested in the usage, but in the total space -- so I think df is the right tool.  I am interested in why more the 20G seems to be available when my pod requested 20GB.

Comment: The total space is going to be the space of the actual volume / disk backing the node, which in this case is the 375G SSD,  `emptyDir` does not create the equivalent of a virtual disk.  The kubelet itself tracks usage and will evict the pod if there is resource contention above the limit (as I recall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `emptyDir`, it does not create a virtual/logical disk.  It's basically just using the underlying local storage used by the node itself (which in this case is the SSD).  Further, request limits don't work the way you think, meaning you won't end up with a volume backed by a 20G "disk".  The kubelet will monitor the storage used by your volume and if it detects that storage usage exceeds the limit, it will mark the pod for eviction.

I believe to do what you want, you'll need to wait for [generic ephemeral volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes) to mature.

Comment: So does this mean the request is just used for scheduling?  Meaning, could I schedule 18 of my pods on this node (for 360GB), at least as far as ephemeral storage is concerned?  Regarding contention: would it then be fine if one pod used all 360GB, and the other pods used zero?

Comment: I updated my answer as it did not read correctly.  I believe if the kubelet detects that the container/pod has exceeding the limit, it will make the pod for eviction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Do you know if a process in a container can know what the limit is?

Comment: I can't think of a way that would not involve actually calling a Kube API.  I think the generic ephemeral volumes feature will solve all of this for you (eventually)

Comment: As an aside, I like your username - clever!